# Can Select Same Date in NG-Bootstrap Datepicker in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, ng-bootstrap, angular-forms

I am using a date range datepicker using the ng-bootstrap datepicker. But I have a problem encountered. I should be able to select the same date. How will i able to fix this? Please check this link 
[CLICK HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/range-date-picker-ng-bootstrap?file=app%2Fdatepicker-range.html)

```
onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date.after(this.fromDate)) {
      this.toDate = date;
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hmm.. From what I can infer from your question, you want to be able to select the same date for both `fromDate` and `toDate`?

Comment: @wentjun. Yes. You got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> remove third validator in `else if`

check example[range-date-picker](https://stackblitz.com/edit/range-date-picker-ng-bootstrap-dtxdxi?file=app/datepicker-range.ts)

**original one**

```
onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date.after(this.fromDate)) {
      this.toDate = date;
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }
```

**fixed one**

```
onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.toDate = date;
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your function

```
  onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date.after(this.fromDate)) {
      this.toDate = date;
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }
```

With

```
  onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.toDate = date;
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date.after(this.fromDate)) {
      this.toDate = date;
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }
```

with

```
onDateSelection(date: NgbDate) {
    if (!this.fromDate && !this.toDate) {
      this.fromDate = date;
    } else if (this.fromDate && !this.toDate && date && (date.equals(this.fromDate)) || date.after(this.fromDate)) {
      this.toDate = date;
    } else {
      this.toDate = null;
      this.fromDate = date;
    }
  }
```